# two dropdown form and value from both forms should email to the specific email address

Tags: php, forms, email, get

I have two forms, one has option value and one of 5 values would be selected, after selecting the value and submit it/or pressing continue it would instantly go to another page where would be another form what has few other text values. After submitting this form one email should go to my email address with all the information from first and second form.

I am having problem with processing this, please help.

example- http://www.1800dentist.com/lp/form-widget4-478/

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

yeah on page two add input type hidden which has value from form one.
then on submitting form two all values can be send